# Why can't I set a List of objects from similar classes in different packages

Tags: java, list, copy

I have 2 similar classes with identical fields but they reside in different packages.  After walking the source A class and copy the data, Java won't allow me to call a set method on target B class to transfer data from A to B.

```
public class A { //reside in package A
    public List<QuestionTemplate> qTemplateList;
}

public class QuestionTemplate { //reside in package A
    public List<QuestionList> qList;
}

public class QuestionList { //reside in package A
    public String questionText;
    public String questionChoice;
}
```

---

```
public class B { //reside in package B
    public List<QuestionTemplate> qTemplateList;
}

public class QuestionTemplate { //reside in package B
    public List<QuestionList> qList;
}

public class QuestionList { //reside in package B
    public String questionText;
    public String questionChoice;
}
```

I tried walking the the A class list and gather the data and created a ListCopy.  Then call B class set method and send in the ListCopy just created from A class.

```
A a = new A();

..

List<QuestionTemplate> templateListCopy = new LinkedList<>();
for (QuestionTemplate template : a.qTemplateList) {
    List<QuestionList> questionListCopy = new LinkedList<>();
    for (QuestionList question : template.qList) {
        QuestionList questionCopy = new QuestionList();
        questionCopy.questionText = question.questionText;
        questionCopy.questionChoice = question.questionChoice;
        questionListCopy.add(questionCopy);
    }
    QuestionTemplate questionTemplateCopy = new QuestionTemplate();
    questionTemplateCopy.qList = questionListCopy;
    templateListCopy.add(questionTemplateCopy);
}

B b = new B();
b.setQuestionTemplates(templateListCopy); // error on this line:
```

the error is:

```
setQuestionTemplates(List<A.QuestionTemplate>) in class A cannot be applied to (List<B.QuestionTemplate>)
```

What to do now?

Comment: The message is pretty clear. If you go to a shop in the US and try to pay in Australian dollars, that won't work, because the shop expects US dollars. The fact that both currrencies have "dollar" in their name doesn't make them the same currency. If a method expects a list of A.QuestionTemplate, you can't pass it a list of B.QuestionTemplate. Because A.QuestionTemplate and B.QuestionTemplate are different types, even though they both happen to have QuestionTemplate in their name.

Comment: The fact that the class names are equal is completely meaningless, the classes are in different packages and have NOTHING in common (except Object) unless you explicitly let them extend the same base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete QuestionList and QuestionTemplate for example from package B and after that in class B you will have to import QuestionList and QuestionTemplate from package A.

Comment: I am not convinced this will work, as there is still no `IS-A` relationship between `A` and `B`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a collection of similar classes I advise you to read about polymorphism :)

Example

Like @ luk2302 said you should create class QuestionTemplate and then implement two classes.

- first:

  QuestionTemplateA extends QuestionTemplate
- second:

  QuestionTemplateB extends QuestionTemplate

and you can create new collections of QuestionTemplate where you can put both classes

```
List<QuestionTemplate> list = new ArrayList<>();
QuestionTemplateA a = new QuestionTemplateA();
QuestionTemplateB b = new QuestionTemplateB();
list.add(a);
list.add(b);
```